# Unable to open my jnlp file on open web start using JVM 1.17 but I am able to open same with JVM 1.8

Tags: java, jvm, jnlp, jide, openwebstart

While I am trying to open my jnlp file using on open web start using JVM 1.17, I am getting the following errors but it is opening fine with JVM 1.8.

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Launch Error: Could not launch JNLP file. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws/browser from the command line and send a bug report.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:413)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.access$300(Launcher.java:71)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:660)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:406)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.jidesoft.plaf.LookAndFeelFactory (in unnamed module @0x30d1453f) cannot access class com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows to unnamed module @0x30d1453f
    at com.jidesoft.plaf.LookAndFeelFactory.installJideExtension(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.plaf.LookAndFeelFactory.installJideExtension(Unknown Source)
    at com.ericsson.charging.vxmlivr.editor.core.common.CommonUtils.setLookAndFeel(CommonUtils.java:342)
    at com.ericsson.charging.vxmlivr.editor.workflow.client.gui.WorkflowEditorFrame.main(WorkflowEditorFrame.java:663)
    ... 7 more
```

My jnlp file is working fine with jvm 1.8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
      codebase="https://214.5.247.200:13202/EditorServer/">        
    <information>
      <title>Workflow Editor</title>
      <vendor>Ericsson</vendor>
      <description>Workflow Editor</description>
     
      <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/> 
    </security>  

    <resources>         
    <jar href="client/CXC1729877-EditorCore.jar" main="true" download="eager"/> 
    <jar href="client/CXC1729512-WorkflowClient.jar" main="true" download="eager"/> 
    <jar href="lib/commonlookandfeel.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/JGo.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/JGoLayout.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-action.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-beaninfo.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-common.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-components.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-dashboard.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-dialogs.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-dock.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-editor.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-grids.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/activation.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jsr173_1.0_api.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-codec-1.15.jar"/>
    <extension name="EditorServerLogging.jsp" href="jspFiles/com/ericsson/charging/vxmlivr/editor/server/EditorServerLogging.jsp"/>
    <j2se version="1.8+"     java-vm-args="-Xincgc" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="512m" />

    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="abc">
    <argument>214.xyz</argument>
    <argument>13202</argument>
    <argument>https</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Thankyou.

Tried to add java-vm-args="-Djide.defaultStyle=1" in my jnlp, Still not working.
If instead of 1.8+ j2se, I will use 1.8* i.e 1.8 version only it is working fine

Comment: I am using it's alternate Open webstart to open my jnlp file.

Comment: There is no “JVM 1.17”. When the look and feel is incompatible with Java 17, check whether a) there is a newer version or b) you really need this look & feel. Besides that, the option `-Xincgc` was deprecated even in Java 8 and has no use in Java 17.